# At many places vs. in many places

Tags: prepositions, exam-questions

I have an error spotting question.

> That summer, elections were (A) held at many a place (B) without any untoward incident. (C) No error. (D)

I think the sentence is free of errors, but according to the book which I have, the error is in part B: *held at many a place*.

Now in part B, *many a place*, which means "many places" is correct; *held* is also correct, so I am left with **at**, which I think is also correct, but since the book says the error is in B, it is the only part where I have confusion.

What should it be? *At many a place*, *in many a place*, or something else?

Comment: The preposition *at* is wrong, it should be *in*.  But as a native speaker, I honestly have no idea why, so I won't add an answer in.  Prepositions are funny things!

Comment: @Choirbean Do we always use 'in' with "elections were held __ many places ""  ?

Comment: With exactly that formation, yes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem seems to be centered around

> elections

since elections are held **in** many locations, whereas

> Festivals and rock concerts are held **at** many different locations.

Possibly because an election occurs *within* a constituency.

Top add to the confusion,

> Polling stations have been located **at** major intersections throughout town.